# A functional operator involving second-order primitives

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm looking for an operator $F \ \colon C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) $ on the space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ of smooth maps on the real line so that for each $g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$\frac{{\rm d} ^2}{{ \rm d}  x^2}g  = g  \ \ \frac{{\rm d} ^2}{{ \rm d}  x^2}  F(g).$$

In other words, I would like to explicitly write in terms of $g$ a map whose second derivative is $ \frac{1}{g}\frac{{\rm d} ^2}{{ \rm d}  x^2}g  $.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Maybe $$g\to \int_0^x \left( \int_0^t \frac{g''(s)}{g(s)} ds\right) dt$$